# How to write rightclick method in selenium testng

Tags: selenium, testng

How to do i rightclick on a webelement selenium testng? 
i have given you example for doubleclick, likewise i need for rightclick method.please give me best one.

```
public static void doubleclickOn(String objLocator1){                   

            try
            {
            findWebElement(objLocator1);


            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
        org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action action = actions.doubleClick(webElement).build();
            action.perform();
            APP_LOGS.debug("double Clicked on "+locatorDescription);
            //System.out.println(locator);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                APP_LOGS.debug("FAIL : The locator "+locator+" of description "+locatorDescription+": does not exists in webpage:");
                Reporting.fail("FAIL : The locator "+locator+" of description "+locatorDescription+": does not exists in webpage:");

            }
```

}

thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to formulate code yourself, and then paste that in case you run into a roadblock, rather than asking people to completely do your work. Meet your end halfway, so that people will help you out in meeting the other end. :)

Comment: im not asking people without knowing, just clarifying, i written the doubleclick code subh, and too tried the rightclick method in the same way of double click, its working fine too. but its working slow, soo i need better than what i did

Comment: im not asking the people to do my work fully. @subh

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. If you had submitted the code for context click and then asked something related to optimization or other alternative, it would've been a different story. People tend to mark negative to such questions in here. Hence, I am just asking you to take precautions.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

**Assuming "*objlocator1*" consists of xpath of the webelement to right-click on.**

```
public static void rightClickOn(String objLocator1){                   

            try
            {
            findWebElement(objLocator1);


            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
            actions.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath(objLocator1)));
            actions.perform();

            APP_LOGS.debug("Context Clicked on "+locatorDescription);
            //System.out.println(locator);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                APP_LOGS.debug("FAIL : The locator "+locator+" of description "+locatorDescription+": does not exists in webpage:");
                Reporting.fail("FAIL : The locator "+locator+" of description "+locatorDescription+": does not exists in webpage:");

            }
```

Comment: My bad. I have edited the code now for context click. It was double click earlier.

Comment: same code was done before for rightclick method . actually when im running my program, rightclick on the object locator is slow. so i need other alternative for rightclick

Comment: As far as I know, there are just two methods in Selenium-webdriver for right clicking, namely **contextClick()** and **contextClick(WebElement Onelement)**. And, since you want to right click on a certain element, the later one will suffice. As for being slow, it is browser-dependent**(FYI, IE is comparatively slow, then Firefox and Chrome)**. I am afraid that's how it is.

Comment: @Vids: There is no other optimal way other than this as far as Selenium is concerned. You can, however, tweak your xpath(in case you are using that) to make it relative. But, that won't amount to much..

Comment: i have one more query that when we using the automation in web application, my program pass in one time and same program fails in one time.if it is happend? what to do?

Comment: Most of the time it happens because selenium is not able to detect the presence of the element to be located, as the element might not have loaded yet. So, **try to give implicit and explicit waits** as explained here in [this link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp), wherever necessary.

Comment: Implicit wait gives a global timeout, i.e., each time selenium tries to find an element, it will wait for a maximum of that time. In case some element takes more than that, then you can override the implicit wait by providing explicit wait for that element.

Comment: both implicit and explicit can be given in same element??

Comment: Like I said **Implicit wait** is a global timeout and it's not restricted to one element. When declared, it works for all elements equally. **Explicit wait** can be given explicitly to any element(s).

Comment: i have one doubt, in testng, when im running the single testcases doest throw any error . when im running multiple testcases in testng.xml . it throws error in some testcases.why it is happening
?i gave thread.sleep also. @subh

Comment: @Vids, sorry. I can't help you with testng. I don't have much knowledge in it. Please ask a new question, so others can help you out. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click action in Selenium web driver can be done using **Actions** class.

Also known as **Context Click**.

**1) Below is the code to demonstrate right click operation using Actions class.**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));
actions.contextClick(elementLocator).perform();
```

**2) To select the item from the context menu**

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);  
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));    
action.contextClick(elementLocator).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform(); 
//adjust keys.ARROW_DOWN accordingly
```